# Compare 2 ranges of cells and return a value from a 3rd range of cells in excel

Tags: excel

I create my work's employee schedule and I am having trouble.  I have a year long spreadsheet where each column is one day. I have two rows that I need to compare values in up to a certain day (column).  When the latest match is found, I want the cell to return the date from a third row corresponding to the column of the latest match.  Here is what I have so far:

`{=INDEX($L$6:$NM$6, MATCH("X"&"DTP",$L$3:$NM$3&$L8:$NM8,0))}`

Where `"X"` is a conditional value, `"DTP"` is the job assignment, and columns `L6-NM6` are the days of the year.  However, this only returns the first instance that both conditions are true, not the last. So I tried:

`{=INDEX($L$6:$NM$6, 1, MAX(IF($L$3:$NM$3="X"&$L8:$NM8="DTP",COLUMN($L$3:$NM$3)-COLUMN($L$3)+1&COLUMN($L8:$NM8)-COLUMN($L8)+1)))}`

However, this only returned `January 1, 2017`.

Both of these attempts still don't include a date limit to give me the highest date before the next month's schedule.

If I try to include a date limit in the second attempt above, I put:

`{=INDEX($L$6:$NM$6<$B$1.....(with all the rest the same)`

Where `B1` contains the date the function is to look up to and stop.  With this, the overall function simply returns `TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *array formula*

`=AGGREGATE(14,6,L6:NM6/((L3:NM3="X")*(L8:NM8="DTP")), 1)`

Will fetch you *the largest date from row6 where row3 is "X" and row8 is "DTP"*. It should work even if the days are not sorted. But since they are, it's expected to return the "rightmost" match.

The formula forces a div/0 in the cells that don't match the criteria, so that  the parameter `6` (ignore errors) will drop them from the search for the max (param 14).

Comment: This worked beautifully.  Thank you very much, I had spent days on this.